# Print back quote in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to print back quotes ` between values in PowerShell. I'm trying to do this because I am sending data to Azure DevOps and need certain values to be marked as code (it uses Markdown).

For example:

```
$names = @("A","B","C")
```

`$names` should print just how the letter B had the back quote first

```
`A, `B, `C
```

I've tried adding the back quote in several different ways to display it but nothing works

```
`$_.names
'\
```

Can printing the back-quote even be achieved?

Comment: Are you looking for ``$names | % { '`' + $_ }`` or ``$names | % { '`{0}' -f $_ }``?

Comment: It depends, in a double quoted string double the backtick, in a single quoted string a single backtick should show as is. Escaping in comments is a nuisance.

Comment: @LotPings, wow that was easy... it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks for the comment, LotPings's comment was what I needed. Thanks!